# JS - HTTP Request using result in different function

Tags: javascript

I have a GET request to get data (a string) from an URL using following code:

```
var https = require('https');
let urldata;

var options = {
    host: 'test.com',
    path: '/test.php'
}
var request = https.request(options, function (res) {
    let data = '';
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        urldata = data; 
        console.log(urldata);  //Returns the retrieved data from URL into console
    });
});
request.end();
```

Now I have a second function that needs the data that I get from the Request abvoe:

```
async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
    message.author.send(urldata);
}
```

The issue with that is "urldata" is "undefined" in the second function because the first one is async and didn't give a result yet. I've read that I will have to use "callback" or "promise" in order to use the data from the first function in my second one. I tried around with that but couldn't get a working result.

It would be awesome if someone could help me out with recoding this to a callback or promise so the data from the first function could be used for the second function.

Comment: where is `execute` function called from? You probably want to call it inside the callback function of `res.on("end", ...)`

Comment: that did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

```js
const urldata = await Promise(resolve => {
    var request = https.request(options, function (res) {
        let data = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            resolve(data)
        });
    });
    request.end();
})

console.log(urldata);  //Returns the retrieved data from URL into console

// Now you can run the second function with "urldata" in it
```

Comment: I don't know why but this doesn't give me anything, not even an error.
As soon as I add the "const urldata = await Promise(resolve => {" around the function it just doesnt start.

Comment: Can you explain me the steps you are using to run this code